# .factory not working in Visual Studio's Cordova

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, cordova

I'm trying to run my sample Angular code in Apache Cordova but what seems to be working in standalone Angular, does not work in Visual Studio when using Apache Cordova.

The method was taken from the AngularJS tutorial by Scott Allen at Pluralsight. I used this on 'standalone' angular and it worked: http://plnkr.co/edit/P12BG2eDaCR7PsNzGGFV. But why not in Cordova?

I have two files:

```
(function () {

    var req = function ($http) {

        var getTest = function (username) {
            return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        });
        };
        return {
            getTest: getTest
        };
    };

    var module = angular.module("starter.controllers");
    module.factory("req", req);

}());
```

and

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('BrowseCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, req) {

    var myTest = req.getTest("test");

});
```

Unfortunately I end up getting

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: reqProvider <- req <-
>   BrowseCtrl

All the problems related to this error I found were related to reintialisation of the module by adding "[]" but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... My method is fine, I just forgot to include the req.js file in the index.html of the project

```
(...)
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/req.js"></script>
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First just learn AngularJs then use Cordova

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

myApp.factory('MyService', function ($http, sessionService, $location, $window) { 
   return {
      req: function (data) {
         $http({
            async: false,
            method: 'GET',
            url: "",
            //headers: { 'Authorization': 'bearer ' + session.sessionId }
         })
         .success(function (data) {

         }).error(function (error) {

         });
      }
   }
});



myApp .controller('nameController', ['$http','MyService', function ( $http, MyService) {
 MyService.req(data);
}]);
```

To connection between controller you must use services.
Is many free tutorial about AngularJs.
Good luck :)